# How to replace default json serializer in YugaByteCassandraCSharpDriver?

Tags: c#, yugabytedb

Is there any way to replace json default serializer?

I implement a serializer which convert json to objects, so i can use Custome classes in my model instead of string

```
    public class JsonSerializer<T> : TypeSerializer<T>
    {
        public override ColumnTypeCode CqlType => ColumnTypeCode.Json;
        public override T Deserialize(ushort protocolVersion, byte[] buffer, int offset, int length, IColumnInfo typeInfo)
        {
            string json = PrimitiveStringSerializer.Deserialize(protocolVersion, buffer, offset ,length, typeInfo);
            return (T)json.FromDbJsonString();
        }

        public override byte[] Serialize(ushort protocolVersion, T value)
        {
            string json = value.ToDbJsonString();
            return PrimitiveStringSerializer.Serialize(protocolVersion, json);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible only using fork.

If it is acceptable to you, just put your serializer here:
`{ ColumnTypeCode.Json, TypeSerializer.PrimitiveJsonSerializer }`
in src/Cassandra/Serialization/Serializer.cs

Comment: Actually i was looking for a built-in solution. As a greedy solution i can replace `TypeSerializer.PrimitiveJsonSerializer` with reflection which i think it is easier than forking.